# Small alter table hangs indefinitely on MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run an `ALTER TABLE` to add a column on a 200 row table in MySQL. It works fine locally on a few boxes, but hangs indefinitely (have let it run up to 5 minutes) in production.

Doing a `SHOW processlist;` I can see that it is `Waiting for table metadata lock` this whole time. The processlist shows that it is the oldest query running, so I have no idea what it's waiting on, or why whatever it's waiting on won't finish or get killed by MySQL. Any ideas?

The transactions section of `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G` is as follows:

```
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 4148381
Purge done for trx's n:o < 4148307 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 699
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 4148291, not started
MySQL thread id 123643, OS thread handle 0x7f392b31d700, query id 467771426 some_ip root cleaning up
---TRANSACTION 4148286, not started
MySQL thread id 123642, OS thread handle 0x7f392b538700, query id 467771334 some_ip root cleaning up
---TRANSACTION 4148280, not started
MySQL thread id 123641, OS thread handle 0x7f39304ee700, query id 467771083 some_ip root cleaning up
---TRANSACTION 4148274, not started
MySQL thread id 123640, OS thread handle 0x7f392b569700, query id 467771047 some_ip root cleaning up
---TRANSACTION 4148268, not started
MySQL thread id 123639, OS thread handle 0x7f392b102700, query id 467770952 some_ip root cleaning up
---TRANSACTION 4148263, not started
MySQL thread id 123638, OS thread handle 0x7f39304bd700, query id 467770703 some_ip root cleaning up
---TRANSACTION 0, not started
MySQL thread id 123635, OS thread handle 0x7f392b507700, query id 467770298 some_ip root cleaning up
---TRANSACTION 4148245, not started
MySQL thread id 123634, OS thread handle 0x7f392b443700, query id 467770261 some_ip root cleaning up
---TRANSACTION 4148230, not started
MySQL thread id 123633, OS thread handle 0x7f392b753700, query id 467770267 some_ip root cleaning up
---TRANSACTION 4148303, not started
MySQL thread id 123632, OS thread handle 0x7f392b2ec700, query id 467771749 some_ip root Waiting for table metadata lock
ALTER TABLE some_table
---TRANSACTION 4148379, not started
MySQL thread id 123568, OS thread handle 0x7f393048c700, query id 467775687 some_ip root cleaning up
---TRANSACTION 4148380, not started
MySQL thread id 123563, OS thread handle 0x7f392b68f700, query id 467775899 some_ip root cleaning up
---TRANSACTION 4148373, not started
MySQL thread id 123562, OS thread handle 0x7f392b228700, query id 467774889 some_ip root cleaning up
---TRANSACTION 0, not started
MySQL thread id 123453, OS thread handle 0x7f392b474700, query id 467775900 some_ip root init
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
---TRANSACTION 4148302, ACTIVE 143 sec
MySQL thread id 123645, OS thread handle 0x7f392b6c0700, query id 467771503 some_ip root cleaning up
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 4148303, sees < 4148303
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your code... Perhaps another proccess is locking the table?

Comment: What code? The ALTER table statement?

Comment: Post the output of `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G`

Comment: Is there a reason this was downvoted? Can I do anything else to make the question clearer?

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue in our Production. The problem was another service was accessing the database and when trying to run an Alter Command will put into indefinite loop.

In our case,

1. we stopped application server - Weblogic
2. Ran ALTER Command
3. Restarted DB instance
4. Restarted Weblogic instance.

Answer (score -1):

try "FLUSH TABLES" before ALTER